# Android studio ругается на add в ArrayList

Tags: java, android-studio

**Cannot resolve symbol 'add'**

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("text")
```

Comment: Попробуйте list.add("text") делать в onCreate(),   либо в методе, который потом будете вызывать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавление элементов необходимо производить в каком-либо методе, а не просто  теле класса.